# Reset toggled classes after window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I'm trying to make my mobile menu behave like the one on this site:
[www.wearenation.co.uk](https://www.wearenation.co.uk/)**

On the site I've referenced, if you open the mobile menu in a window with width < 1001px, then resize to a larger width, the menu stays closed, even if you resize to < 1001px again. I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve the same thing.

Right now, clicking my mobile nav 'burger' toggles four separate classes:

```
//---HTML---//

<button class="burger navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" 
type="button" id="button">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
  <div class="topping"></div><!-- Need 'topping' css -->
</button>

//---jQuery---//

//Toggles 'burger' animation
$('.burger').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

//Toggles white-bg to cover content when menu slides out
$("#button").click(function() {
 $('.cloak-hide').toggleClass('cloak-hide-active');
});

//Toggles menu transform 
$("#button").click(function() {
 $('.menu-transform').toggleClass('menu-transform-active');
});

//Fades in Text on Mobile Nav
$("#button").click(function() {
 $('.mobile-nav-transition').toggleClass('mobile-nav-transition-
active');
});
```

**Until now, I simply 'hid' the mobile menu when width > 768px with a CSS media query.**

**The issue is: the nav is still active, just hidden.** This becomes apparent if you resize your window *back* to <768px. **I'm trying to figure out how to make a >768px width resize completely reset the nav, so when you return to a smaller width it isn't active.**

This involves attaching different classes (.burger, .cloak-hide, etc.) to an event that fires when window width > 768px. I'm trying to figure out the best way to 're-toggle' the classes without triggering CSS transitions.

**To give an example**: when the burger is clicked, 'menu-transform-active' is added to an element with class 'menu-transform', going from 'transform: translate3d(100,0,0)' to 'transform: translate3d(0,0,0)'. Upon resizing the window >768px, this value needs to return to default *instantly*, without triggering 'transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);' added to the 'menu-transform' class.

I've been experimenting with a few different methods for achieving this, but haven't had any luck as of yet.

Here's the mobile-nav HTML

```
<div class="mobile-menu menu-transform d-flex flex-column">
<div class="logo-top-margin"><a href="index.html" class="no-click logo 
white-text">Company</a></div>

<ul class="subtitle mb-auto mt-auto textdiv">

    <li class="menu-list-element">
      <a href="index.html">
        <div class="resp-font-menu mobile-nav-transition white-text">
          Home
        <span class="underline menu-underline white-text">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li><!-- menu-list-element -->

    <li class="menu-list-element">
      <a href="work.html">
        <div class="resp-font-menu mobile-nav-transition white-text">
          Work
        <span class="underline menu-underline white-text">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li><!-- menu-list-element -->

    <li class="menu-list-element">
      <a href="about.html">
        <div class="resp-font-menu mobile-nav-transition white-text">
          About
        <span class="underline menu-underline white-text">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li><!-- menu-list-element -->

    <li class="menu-list-element">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <div class="resp-font-menu mobile-nav-transition white-text">
          Contact
        <span class="underline menu-underline white-text">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li><!-- menu-list-element -->

  </ul><!-- subtitle -->

<ul class="menu-footer-content mobile-nav-transition subtitle textdiv">
<li class="mb-2 d-flex">
  <a class="d-flex" href="#">
    <span class="white-text ml-2 align-items-
center">#</span></a>
</li>
<li class="mb-1">
  <ul class="social subtitle p-0 d-flex align-items-center">
    <li class="mr-3">
      <a class="d-flex">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="mr-3">
      <a class="d-flex">

      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="mr-3">
      <a class="d-flex">

      </a>
    </li>
  </ul><!-- social -->
</li><!-- mb-1 -->
<li>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <span class="white-text">SoandsoCo.</span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul><!-- menu-footer-content -->
</div><!-- mobile-menu -->
```

...and the relevant CSS

```
//Hide page content when mobile nav is active

.cloak{
    opacity: 1;
}
.cloak-hide{
    -webkit-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    -moz-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    -o-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    -ms-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}
.cloak-hide-active{
    opacity: 0;
}

//Reveal Mobile Nav Text

.mobile-nav-transition{
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .3s;
    -o-transition-delay: .3s;
    -ms-transition-delay: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.mobile-nav-transition-active{
    opacity: 1;
}

//Apply x-axis transform

.menu-transform {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  -moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  -o-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  -ms-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}
.menu-transform-active {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
}
```

Greatful for any feedback, advice, or constructive criticism!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `resize` event to remove all active classes when screen width goes above 768px.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var sWidth = $( window ).width();
  if(sWidth > 768) {
    $('.burger').removeClass('active');
    $('.cloak-hide').removeClass('cloak-hide-active');
    $('.menu-transform').removeClass('menu-transform-active');
    $('.mobile-nav-transition').removeClass('mobile-nav-transition-active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm trying this out now

Comment: Hey Dan, this was the solution I was looking for! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Androbaut Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you set transitions to their own class you can toggle the ability for the animation to run. This will allow you to deactivate the menu 'instantly' without transitions taking place.

So instead of just toggling the opacity state, toggle the transition state first then set the opacity. If the transition class is there it animates, if it's not it doesn't. I'd say what you have is close.

As @Dan Philip mentioned; `$(window).resize()` is how you can detect the resize event.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for suggestion! I'm almost laughing over here since that seems so obvious in hindsight... :$

Comment: Implemented what you've suggested & it's working like a charm. Thanks again 